# if a web page is iframe on example.com site it shows some data not full page

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

I want to make only website (example.com) to open in an iframe pages from my website (mydomain.com). In the iframe it should show a different content from the original page linked in the iframe.

```
<?php
$url="http://example.com";
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '$url'))
{
echo 'This content gose on iframe page only for http://example.com ';
else {
echo "This content for main web page (mydomain.com) and other websites where this webpage is iframed ";
}
?>
```

I have added the sample code which show what I want to code?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here. *(Consult my edit below).*

Firstly, variables do not get parsed in single quotes.

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "$url"))
```

or just remove them

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $url))
```

You also have a missing closing brace `}` for this conditional statement:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '$url'))
{
```

---

```
$url="http://example.com";
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $url))
{
echo 'This content gose on iframe page only for http://example.com ';
} // This one was missing
else {
echo "This content for main web page (mydomain.com) and other websites where this webpage is iframed ";
}
```

and that alone would have thrown you something about it to the effect of:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in /path/to/file.php on line x

had error reporting been set.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

**Edit:**

However:

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` will give you:

`/some-dir/yourpage.php`

which I doubt you want to use here, or should use since it will fail.

You may have wanted to use:

```
$url = strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (

($url=="www.example.com/file.xxx") 

||

($url=="example.com/file.xxx") )

{
echo 'This content gose on iframe page only for http://example.com ';
}
else {
echo "This content for main web page (mydomain.com) and other websites where this webpage is iframed ";
}
```

**N.B.:** There is no need to add the `http://` in my above edit, since it will populate itself automatically.

You can also use:
(Note: Do not add `http://` or `http://www.` or anything else, only the server's name).

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], "example.com") !== false)
```

---

Another method you can use if you want to check if it's coming from a specific folder/file:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strrpos($url, "http://www.example.com/folder/file.php") !== false)
```

Note that the use of `!== false` is very important here and `=== true` will fail if you were to change it to that, in order to try to check for truthness and will give a false positive, so don't use `=== true`.

Also note that `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` are not the same. You will need to use the one that fits the criteria specifically.

Comment: not working just showing result for all "This content for main web page (mydomain.com) and other websites where this webpage is iframed"

Comment: @WaseemShahzada I've made a few edits since my initial post and you need to reload them. Plus, if you have extra code that you're not showing and may prove to be relevant, add it in an edit in your question. I've tested this before posting.

Comment: thanks for Your reply but i m still not getting only "else" codition in output for all on the main webpage and also on webpage where its framed

Comment: @WaseemShahzada Like I asked earlier; edit your question with your full/real code as to where the frame or iframe is and how you're using it. I have no idea at all as to why it's failing you here and if you are using `.php` extension etc. etc. etc.